# Effecient algorithm to build a linear order on a set of states of automaton

Tags: algorithms, automata, discrete-mathematics

Is there an algorithm that help to build a linear order on a set of states of automaton (without output signals), such that this order is compatible with a transtion function of automaton?

Let A = (X, S, δ) be an automaton, where X is a set of states, S is a set of input signals, δ: X × S → X is a transition function. Need to build a linear order ≤ on the set X, such that for any s∈S from x≤y it follows that δ(x,s)≤δ(y,s).

Please suggest some algorithm that can be more efficient that backtracking algorithm.

Comment: This is not always possible. For example, consider the automaton with two states $x, y$, $S = \{s\}$ and such that $\delta(x, s) = y$ and $\delta(y, s) = x$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But it is interesting to know - is there any criteria, or at least sufficient conditions, when automaton can be ordered linearly... It's clear that when we have any cycle in transition graph, then such automaton cannot be ordered.

Comment: The automaton could be ordered, even if there is a cycle. Consider for example $X = \{x, y,\}$, $S = \{a, b\}$ and $\delta(x, a) = \delta(y, a) = x$, $\delta(x, b) = \delta(y, b) = y$.

Comment: So, my question is about existing of criteria when we can say about possibility of ordering for automaton.

Comment: Then you should edit your post to mention it!